# Capturing audio or provide access to microphone in android

Tags: android, audio, microphone

I tried work with **MediaRecorder** for capturing audio. As I see  the **MediaRecorder** output only file. Did we output audio to stream or maybe have access to microphone with anything libs?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here:
[record audio in android](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html)

```
public class SoundRecordingActivity extends Activity {

  MediaRecorder recorder;
  File audiofile = null;
  private static final String TAG = "SoundRecordingActivity";
  private View startButton;
  private View stopButton;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startButton = findViewById(R.id.start);
    stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stop);
  }

  public void startRecording(View view) throws IOException {

    startButton.setEnabled(false);
    stopButton.setEnabled(true);

    File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try {
      audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", sampleDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
      return;
    }
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
  }

  public void stopRecording(View view) {
    startButton.setEnabled(true);
    stopButton.setEnabled(false);
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
  }

  protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for answer, but i try found way work with sound data in real time. For example: get sound intesivity(**MediaRecorder** provide this parametr) or other parametr.